# How to include view variable inside zend translate expression?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate, poedit

I want to display latest 3 news at my homepage. I select the latest news from table from MySql database and assign them to view variables in index controller, like this:

```
$this->view->latestNew = $someClass->getNewsfunction();
```

Then I declare it in view:

```
echo $this->translate->_($this->latestNew);
```

assuming that each time I will add a new row in my News table from MySql database, a unique header will be passed to Zend_Translate, which automatically will be detected by Poedit and proposed to be translated. But it won't work. The options like `{$this->latestNew}, '$this->latestNew', "$this->latestNew"` won't work neither. Any ideas?

Comment: What exacly is it not working here ?

Comment: Poedit doesn't recognize echo $this->translate->_($this->latestNew);  if I type echo $this->translate->_('$this->latestNew'); it tries to translate $this->latestNew, not the value which represents this variable.

Comment: I dont know how poedit works, maybe the problem is how poedit cooperates with your app.

Comment: But how would You deal with situation that I've described above? I need the home page to display latest 3 news that I have in my database table and application to be able to translate them automatically, taking the translations from the source files created in advance.

Comment: One more thing: I have just take a look at Your web-site. I noticed that it can be viewed in 3 languages. Assuming that it was developed in Zend Framework, it means that Zend_Translate was used as well. You said that You don't know how Poedit works, so You don't use Gettext. Maybe You can share what adapter You prefer and why?

Comment: I would be using Zend_Translate to load translation file and then use it in view like `$this->translate($this->latestNewsTitle)` or so. Database could be designed to handle the tranlations itself too.

I am using plain array adapter to cover translations.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so insistent. I just want to understand: how Database could be designed to handle the tranlations itself?

Comment: F.e. news row have a title and title is a string to be translated, you have 2 languages in your db. Join your lang and title to get a translation.

Comment: I hope i have helped a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion:

declare a literal to use in poedit and pass a variable as a parameter to it

In your view

```
printf($this->translate->_("title"), $this->latestNew);
```

in poEdit

source text: 'title'
translation text: %s

You can translate the content always with poEdit.